# Seeking boundaries of administrative units of Ireland

Tags: geospatial, ireland

I need to download a shapefile with the boundaries (polygon) of the administrative units (localities level) for Ireland. I have searched diva-gis and osm, but they do not have data to that level.

Comment: Have you tried [GADM](https://gadm.org/download_country_v3.html)? The preview looks more like county-level borders but I can't be sure.

Comment: You may want to check this site: https://wambachers-osm.website/boundaries/ - "OSM Admin Boundaries Map" (note the tiny triangles left to the country/admin unit names in order to open sub-lists)

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what NUTS level you want, this might work:
https://data.gov.ie/dataset/census-2011-boundary-files

Alternatively, you could check the European INSPIRE-Initiative for Administrative Units (Annex I).

Answer (score 2):

Townlands.ie has a decent downloads page with different admin levels:

https://www.townlands.ie/page/download/

There is also the 2016 Census data which has a lot of resources:

https://www.cso.ie/en/census/census2016reports/census2016smallareapopulationstatistics/

Within the Census data is the Small Areas dataset (smallest admin level in Ireland):

https://data.gov.ie/dataset/small-areas-ungeneralised-osi-national-statistical-boundaries-2015